# Create a Kafka Topic from SQL Server Stored Proc?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

My .NET application is stored procedure intensive and I need to create a Kafka topic from a stored procedure.    I have a key process that is running on stored procedure and at the end of that process, I need to create a Kafka topic to trigger the next process from another .NET service. Do we have any documentation for using Kafka in a stored procedure. We use confluent's Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in .NET applications are not "stored procedures". Sure, you can use AdminClient class from Confluent library to create topics.

---

If you literally meant a database stored procedure, and your stored procedure can run arbitrary C# code (which isn't safe), you can do the same, but you could also shell out to `kafka-topics.sh` script..

Alternatively, create your topic elsewhere, and use tools like Debezium to read from the database into Kafka topics, keeping database logic internal to the database. (Have your stored proc write to a new table, if needed)